# `setup.py develop` installs zipped eggs. How to avoid this?

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

I realized that if you do this for `my_pony_project`

```
setup.py develop
```

installs zipped eggs of `install_requires` packages (example `fancy_lib_of_someone_else`). I want to avoid this.

How can I force a normal (not zipped) installation?

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='foo',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=['fancy_lib_of_someone_else>=1.2']
```

**Background**

I want to avoid zipped eggs, since `pip` seems to install packages twice if zipped eggs are used. One time zipped, one time flat :-(

Comment: maybe what you are looking for could be found in this answer: http://goo.gl/ql7nDa

Comment: @jonrsharpe why should I do this? I like dependency management. The new entry in setup.py could be from somee one else. I just want to pull in the dependencies. BTW I prefer apt to dpkg :-)

Comment: @hairesis the link you provide explains why eggs are good. Nice to know. In this use case I want a flat file installation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe why do you want to know?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want a flat file installation, since some package don't handle it. One example: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/589

Comment: A mixture of curiosity and keenness to avoid [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731) - knowing why you're doing it makes it easier for others to suggest workarounds, alternatives, etc.. Could you add your actual example into your question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are right. This is a xy problem. I updated the question to state the background: I want to avoid zipped eggs, since pip seems to install packages twice if zipped eggs are used.

Comment: I've always assumed this is at least one of the reasons why pip can install from a requirements.txt file. Of course, this requires two steps for installation. `pip install -rrequirements.txt` and `pip install package`. In that scenario, even if the requirements are listed in `setup.py`, they won't get installed a second time.

Comment: @Waylan requirements.txt is for setting an environment. It  is not meant to work recursive or like a dependency graph. If `libone` needs `libtwo` req.txt does not help.

Comment: @guetti and yet I have seen packages use it for exactly that purpose. And quite frankly, why isn't your use case "setting up an environment"? Isn't that what installing dependencies is? In fact you specifically stated you are using the "develop" command, so I an assuming you are setting up a development environment. If you don't like how `setup.py` installs your dependencies, then install them how you would like first and it becomes a non-issue. Perhaps not ideal for the end user, but we are talking about developers in a development environment here.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you want to avoid the `setup.py` script from installing eggs for your users, well, that is a different issue which you did not ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question:

On the system where the packages get installed create this file:

~/.distutils.cfg:

```
[easy_install]
zip_ok = False
```

Yes, this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Upgrading to a new pip version should avoid duplicate installs. At the moment we still use version 1.5.6.